Missing folder of Evolution
I am trying to find "usr/share/evolution/ui/evolution-mail-reader.ui" but I have only “evolution-data-server” folder in the “share” folder. No "evolution" folder there.
The developer of Evolution answered me "You need to ask your distribution where your distribution puts things." so here I am.

What is your Ubuntu version? On mine, the file appears to be provided by evolution-common - have you installed that package?

The filename you're looking for starts with a /. Find the package providing that file with dpkg -S /usr/share/evolution/ui/evolution-mail-reader.ui, and install that package.

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 lts. Evolution is installed through Flatpak.

"dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/share/evolution/ui/evolution-mail-reader.ui" is the answer of Terminal for "dpkg -S /usr/share/evolution/ui/evolution-mail-reader.ui".
